# .haccess subdomains and variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, subdomain

hi all I think I'm asking quite a basic question still iI'm having some problems:
i'm working with .htaccess

and from 
http://v1.piattisti.it/v2/v3
I would like to Get

```
$_GET['v1'] 
$_GET['v2'] 
$_GET['v3']
```

at least to solve the first problem i tried

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.piattisti\.it$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?v1=%1 [L]
```

but is not working...
thanks for the support

Comment: What happens when you type `http://v1.piattisti.it/v2/v3` ?

Comment: Do you also want to support `http://v1.piattisti.it/v2/v3/v4/v5/v6` ?

Comment: from v1 to v3 should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?v1=$1&v2=%2&v3=%3 [L]
```

Comment: seems not to work... http://milano.piattisti.it/ at the bottom i'm printing $_GET but is giving an empty array

Comment: I also tryed with the last line with %1 istead $1..... RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?v1=%1&v2=%2&v3=%3 [L]

Answer (score 0):

This should correctly capture those words:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.piattisti\.it$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?v1=%1&v2=$1&v3=$2 [END]
```

If that indeed leaves you with an *empty* `$_GET` superglobal then some other issue interferes, since you at least should get the keys, even with empty values. Maybe some other, additional rewriting is applied?

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).